# How to redirect after download in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, refresh, meta

With below code i am trying to change browser page.

```
$pdf->Output($pdf_file_name, 'D');   //Downloading PDF

header("Refresh: 3; url='http://example.com/search-form/'");
```

Problem : it is working in FireFox but not working in Chrome and IE.

I need to work this  in Chrome/IE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set headers before output, so just do it the other way round:

```
header("Refresh: 3; url='http://example.com/search-form/'");

$pdf->Output($pdf_file_name, 'D');   //Downloading PDF
```

For this to work, your browser needs to support this header "action". It's an ugly hack and simply not possible (without proper client support) this way as per the http definition of a request cycle - one request - one response. Sending additional headers to start another request beside the response needs client support after all. - I would not want to rely on that solution after all.

The solid solution would be accessing the action you want to redirect to in the first place, put an invisible iframe in the rendered view and point that source to your download action, for it to start as soon as the action gets rendered.

You could do many more sofisticated setups including javascript and the like and more redirects to different actions inbetween, but this pretty is straight forward.